# selenium python send_keys file upload only works once

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a few file uploads with selenium and python.

Everything works fine the first file upload but when i try to upload the second file it just does not work. It does not give me errors and when i rerun the script the first upload works fine. The website has a file upload like this:

```
<input class="upload-class" type="file" accept="image/*" aria-label="upload text">
```

I use something like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@class='upload-class']").send_keys("C:\\path\\to\\file.jpg")
```

Comment: Can you share the web page link?

Comment: no sorry it is a private testing page but i also tested modified versions of my script online on test upload sites with two uploads and it also worked only the first time

Comment: You omitted the most important information. 1) What exact errors do you get ? 2) You should post your Python Selenium code as well since it is likely the source of the problem.

Comment: thats the thing i dont get any errors it just does nothing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.